# Adding a hyperlink column to a 'GridView' dynamically (server-side)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, hyperlink, server-side

I have an **ASP.NET** application that reads an XML source and creates columns in a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This same XML source is used to create columns in a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx). The application populates the `DataTable` and then binds the `DataTable` to the `GridView` using server-side code.

Now I want to display a hyperlink in the `GridView` and am not sure how to do it. (Note that the application is not making use of the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event.)

Here is what I have thus far:

```cs
foreach (XmlNode columnNode in columnNodes)
{    
    dc = new DataColumn(columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value,
        Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    boundField = new BoundField();
    boundField.HeaderText = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnDisplayName"].Value;
    boundField.DataField = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value;
    boundField.SortExpression = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value; 
    grdView.Columns.Add(boundField);    
}
```

where `dt` is a `DataTable` and `grdView` is a `GridView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) to accomplish this; it's a type of bound field specifically designed for displaying and formatting hyperlinks.  You only need to slightly update your code:

```
linkField = new HyperLinkField();
linkField.HeaderText = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnDisplayName"].Value;
// The field you want to use as the displayed text of the hyperlink
linkField.DataTextField = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value;
// The field(s) you want to use in the URL behind the hyperlink
linkField.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value };
// The formatting string for your hyperlink.  Use this to build the links the way you want them.
linkField.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "http://yourSiteName/links/{0}";
linkField.SortExpression = columnNode.Attributes["ColumnName"].Value; 
grdView.Columns.Add(linkField);
```

The part you've left out of your question is what you want these hyperlink URLs to look like.  The [`DataNavigateUrlFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx) is pretty flexible (it works like `String.Format`, so you can construct a URL from static text and embedding text from your datafields).